# div that remains in the DOM for all routes

Tags: angular, vimeo

I'm working on an Angular aplication that uses a Vimeo object. I'm Using routing and in one of the components/page, the one where I show a video, I have the following div:

```
<div id="VimeoVideoDiv" class="message-fullarea" data-vimeo-controls="false" data-vimeo-autoplay="false"></div>
```

So, when showing the video page the vimeo renders fine here, it injects an iframe and once you press play it starts buffering and then the video plays. At some point I want to pause the video and move to another page to capture some data. After Submiting the data, I want to redirect the user to the video page and continue playing the video from where it was left. The problem is that the video starts playing from the beginning. You might think I can set the time to the x seconds where it was paused but doing that it causes a buffering again and that's something I wanted to avoid.

This is due that when routing to the capture data page the video page gets destroyed(removed from DOM). One way I was thinking was to keep the vimeo player div in the app.component.ts, before the router-outlet and somehow inject it to the video page/component.

Is this possible? Any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add it to `app.component.ts` in order to make sure it won't be destroyed.

Another idea is wrapping the components in another component and using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside.

In the module it should be like this:

```
const routes:Routes = [
{path:'', component:VimeoContainerComponent, children: [
    {path: 'somepath', component:SomeComponent },
    {path: '....', .... } ,
    ....
    ]}
]
```

VimeoContainerComponent should look like this:

```
<div id="VimeoVideoDiv" class="message-fullarea" data-vimeo-controls="false" data-vimeo-autoplay="false"></div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now all of its children will be shown, and the div will persist.

Also, you didn't make your `app.component` dirty!

For more info,
https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes

Comment: That's what I am currently trying, but the issue is that now the video renders on top of all pages/components that are specifyed in the routing. For example, in the VimeoComponent I have a title, then the video and then 2 buttons at the bottom and if I set the div above the router-outlet then It will render above the title. Is there a way to show it in a specific place?

Comment: You can use either 'position: absolute/ position: fixed' with `z-index` or exporting it to a component and explicitly decide where it will be in each component by calling it in the specific place

Comment: I got your point. My first attempt was to have the video and form in the same component and hide the video with the [style.display]="showVideo? 'block' : 'none'" but I have some animations for the routes and hide/show and for the block & none is hard to move elements to left/right. Your aproach has the same issue.

Comment: Please be more specific when asking the question so we can help better!

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing a [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy) for your app. That would allow you to detach your video route instead of destroying it, store it and reuse it later. The reused route would render super fast - it's basically like route caching.

It's not a well-documented feature in Angular (or a convenient one, for that matter IMHO), you'll have to look around to see how to use it, but here's something to get you started:

```js
export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  private storedRoutes = new Map<any, DetachedRouteHandle>();

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.isVideoRoute(route);
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    this.storedRoutes.set(route.routeConfig, handle);
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.storedRoutes.has(route.routeConfig);
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    return this.storedRoutes.get(route.routeConfig);
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
  }

  private isVideoRoute(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    // Determine somehow that this is the route containing the video.
  }
}
```

This is a very primitive and flawed implementation, there are many things you might want to do to get it working really well, e.g.:

- manually destroy the stored route if it's not reused at some point;
- use a different mechanism for storing routes;
- implement some method, e.g. `ngOnReactivate`, which is called whenever the route is about to be restored;
- etc.

Comment: I tried that one, I can see that the ngOnDestroy is not called when reusing the video route but the DOM is gone. It does not work unless there is a way to keep the DOM present (hidden of course)

Comment: @Bonomi I see. What about using a secondary router outlet and a simple `display: none`, which is toggled on primary route change?